# cache busting in stenciljs ^2.3.0

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

I have a problem with cache busting in stencil 2.3.0. Maybe someone can help me how he implemented it. Most of the js files are hashed, but unfortunately not in the index.html. /build/app.js and /build/app.esm.js. with cdn and local caching it is difficult to get the current page on some devices. Does anyone have a solution/trick for this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is don't do this... the index.esm.js file is generally very small (~7k) and it is only the definition file for all of the other components.
what we do in my team is: we never cache index.esm.js but we cache every p-*.js forever that way if you change the logic of any of your components, it will be reflected automatically

thx to Michel on Stencil slack for the answer!